# Form Based authentication Configuration in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, forms-authentication

I am trying to configure the Form Based Authentication Configuration in my Windows Server 2008 R2, Sharepoint 2013.

I am unable to add users to aspnetdb in the SQL server.

Can any body tell me how to configure the Form Based Authentication in Windows server 2008 R2?

Comment: If the connection between your SP2013 and SQL is proper and if the aspnetdb is created, then the users will also get created.what are the error you getting, which blog post / article you followed?

Answer (score 2):

Check out my guide here:

http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/

As for populating users, you can use the SharePoint 2013 FBA Pack to add the users (You would have to login with Windows Authentication to add the first user).  Alternatively you can use IIS to add the users, which is described in the guide.